# How to initialize Geofirex with angular/fire

Tags: javascript, angular, angularfire2

I'm using GeoFireX for the first time in a project but I have a question.

I already have Firebase initialized on my Ionic project on the app.module.ts.

How do I got about that with GeoFireX? Since I have to initiate firebase on GeoFireX? On the official documentation it says to initiate like the following?

import * as geofirex from 'geofirex';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

const geo = geofirex.init(firebase);

i copied the question because the guy that asked never got an answer
[GeoFireX Firebase Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58395991/geofirex-firebase-initialization)

Answer (score 1):

found the object i was looking for

```
constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {


}
  geo = geofirex.init(this.db.firestore.app.firebase_);
```

Comment: This is working. If you want to get rid of compilation errors, use this.db.firestore.app['firebase_']

Answer (score 0):

You need to install "agm/core" and "@agm/snazzy-info-window" and added them to app.module

package.json

```
"@agm/core": "1.1.0",
"geofirex": "0.1.0",
"@agm/snazzy-info-window": "1.1.0",
```

app.module

```
...dependencies
export const config = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyBTyQHGGFTooUvfR0_PpfVx8TI8Q7K-0HA',
  authDomain: 'geo-test-c92e4.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://geo-test-c92e4.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'geo-test-c92e4',
  storageBucket: 'geo-test-c92e4.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '200126650097'
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BasicGeoqueryComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyBTyQHGGFTooUvfR0_PpfVx8TI8Q7K-0HA'
    }),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/github/codediodeio/geofirex/tree/master/example

Answer (score 0):

import * as geofirex from 'geofirex';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

Let geoFire = geofirex.init(firebase);
geoFire.point(lat, long)

(this assumes you have         AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)in your app.module.ts file)